# How do I put the homepage link inside the php _e code?

Tags: php

How do I put the homepage link ? Right now it's not correct.

```
     <p><?php _e( 'The page you are looking for is not here. Why don’t you try the <a href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>">homepage</a>?', 'braveandco' ); ?></p>
```

Answer (score 5):

You are using PHP inside a single quote and a malformed one at that. That won't work. Step one is to get that string right:

```
_e( 'The page you are looking for is not here. Why don’t you try the <a href="'.esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ).'">homepage</a>?', 'braveandco' );
```

That is pure PHP. Check PHP's manual for [proper string construction](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php) and for the [concatenation operators](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php).

Now, the [`_e()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/_e) function is a language translation string. That means it is supposed to be replaceable by translations into other languages. Since you have a dynamic component, that translation could be tricky. In fact, what you are doing now [is exactly what the Codex instructs you not to do.](https://codex.wordpress.org/I18n_for_WordPress_Developers#Placeholders) What you want to do instead is provide a stable string for translation then switch in whatever dynamic components you need.

```
printf(
  __( 
    'The page you are looking for is not here. Why don’t you try the <a href="%s">homepage</a>?', 
    'braveandco' 
  ),
  esc_url( home_url( '/' ) )
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like bad syntax - try:

```
 <p><?php _e( 'The page you are looking for is not here. Why don’t you try the <a href="' . esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ) . '">homepage</a>?', 'braveandco' ); ?></p>
```